# JPA create object by id

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a following JPA entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sessions")
public class Session extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

...

}
```

In order to insert new `Session` object into database I need to perform a following steps:

1. Select `user` from db
2. Create new `Session` object, set `user` to this `session` object and then invoke `sessionRepository.save(session)`

Is it possible to avoid step #1 in case I know `user_id` ? I don't want to make redundant select to my database when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EntityManager.getReference()` instead of `EntityManager.find()` (in Spring-data-jpa crud repositories, this operation is named `getOne()`).

This returns a lazy, uninitialized User proxy, without executing any SQL query. Of course, you'd better have a foreign key constraint in the database to make sure the insert fails if you try to insert a new Session for an unexisting user.

Answer (score 1):

There is an API that you can use for this.

If you use JPA, you can use [`entityManager.getReference()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-) for loading user. This will not make a call to the database, unless you do something with the resulting instance.

A Hibernate equivalent for this is [`session.load()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#load(java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable)), which behaves in the same way.